# Paired T-test on several columns with multiple groups in one column

Tags: r

I try to execute a t-test over different groups in a dataframe, and used "by"  and "tapply", but without the wished for results.

I want to do t-test per group (column A, groep "a", "b", etc.) between W-X, W-Y, W-Z, X-Y, X-Z, Y-Z (so all the numerical columns). Any ideas? (this is just a subset of a larger dataset)

```
    A    W      X            Y           Z
1   a   14.0172078  18.7937412  12.277694   16.495175
2   b   6.4176057   -1.8144339  23.0486318  20.142247
3   c   7.8428355   11.9658603  20.9157432  28.58746
4   d   11.8247032  12.8296893  7.8272113   14.358526
5   a   4.2657065   4.7800481   11.5508486  25.431231
6   b   7.883498    15.1155665  20.8919482  26.529425
7   c   11.2701012  7.4366799   5.0557006   15.058677
8   d   18.7653033  10.2386834  8.2821184   18.86291
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a dataframe like yours here:

```
df <- data.frame(A = rep(letters[1:4], 10), W = rnorm(40), X = rnorm(40), Y = rnorm(40), Z = rnorm(40))
```

Now get all possible 2 way combinations of your columns of interest

```
cm <- combn(colnames(df[,2:5]), 2)
cm
```

You can split your dataframe into lists, by the column A, and then apply the paired t test over each 2way column combination:

```
res <- lapply(split(df, df$A), function(x) 
              apply(cm, 2, function(y) t.test(x[,y[1]], x[,y[2]], paired = T)))
```

Note your resuls are now in a list of lists (one for each category in A, length of each sublist determined by your number of column combinations)

```
str(res, max.level = 1)
```

To get results out, eg. pvalue, you can go through these lists:

```
sapply(res, function(x) sapply(x, function(y) y$p.value))
```

And use cm as the rownames, e.g.

```
apply(cm, 2, paste, collapse = "_")
```

Comment: Thanx CCID! I appreciate the concentrated output!

Comment: Thanks @Klass, welcome to the site. If you like the answer, please consider marking it as accepted (see https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Ha CCID, I did, but i first need like 15 credits/reputations before my accepting is accpted : ) You'll see it in due time!